# why do I see this error when I try to install Openai Whisper

Tags: python, openai-whisper

[image]

```
PS C:\> pip install git+https://github.com/openai/whisper.git 
Collecting git+https://github.com/openai/whisper.git
  Cloning https://github.com/openai/whisper.git to c:\users\minju\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-aaszmdk8
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/openai/whisper.git 'C:\Users\minju\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-aaszmdk8'
  Resolved https://github.com/openai/whisper.git to commit 28769fcfe50755a817ab922a7bc83483159600a9
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      ERROR: Can not execute `setup.py` since setuptools is not available in the build environment.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

It's via VS code, and I don't know what's the problem.
Both git and pip are operating fine.

How can I solve that?

Comment: Searched for the error message perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You need `setuptools` installed in your environment. So try `pip install setuptools` in your terminal, and then retry your installation.